# Custom UICollectionView in UITableViewCell in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I'm creating Custom `UICollectionView` in `UITableViewCell` without `Main.Storyboard`. But `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method is not being called, so can you help me to fix it in a best way.

[image]

This is my code:

```
class IndexRow: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

var names:[String] = ["Movie 1","Movie 2","Movie 3","Movie 4","Movie 5","Movie 6"]



@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    print("Hello")
}
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return names.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = self.collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("videoCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell
    //let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: names[indexPath.row])!
    //let dt :NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)!
    print("Hello collection")
    let imageView:UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(5, 5, 180, 270))
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "poster.jpg")
    imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    cell.addSubview(imageView)

    let lableView:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(5,300,180,35))
    lableView.text = names[indexPath.row]
    lableView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    cell.addSubview(lableView)

    return cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let itemsPerRow:CGFloat = 2
    let hardCodedPadding:CGFloat = 0
    let itemWidth = (collectionView.bounds.width / itemsPerRow) - hardCodedPadding
    let itemHeight = collectionView.bounds.height - (hardCodedPadding)
    return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight)
}
```

Comment: `UITableviewCell`  contains  `UICollectionView`correct?

Comment: i don't understand i'm a newbie in swift can you tell me?

Comment: I have given answer check it.

Comment: Evan, you want to check this out: http://www.thorntech.com/2015/08/want-your-swift-app-to-scroll-in-two-directions-like-netflix-heres-how/

Comment: yeah thank you #Payal it's work for me thank you

Comment: so can you tell me how to change CollectionView Vertical -> Horizontal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the delegate is not set, try the following:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
  super.awakeFromNib()
   print("Hello")
  self.collectionView.delegate = self
  self.collectionView.datasource = self
}
```

Comment: i have an orther question in names:[String] i have 5 object but when i set it to UICollectionViewCell it only show 1 object, can you help me for check it?

Comment: oh i know what wrong.. it's vertical now i have to change it to horizontal

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 possible reason for problem :

1. If you bot set delegate  and datasource of tableview and collecionview.
2. Number of rows returning in below method may be zero.

   ```
   func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
   ```
3. If collection view is in cel of tableview then check numberOfRows returning in method of table may be zero.

   ```
   func numberOfRowsInSection(_ section: Int) -> Int
   ```

Reference link :

https://github.com/DahanHu/DHCollectionTableView